# Why am I getting TypeError: array[i] is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, console

So in my program, I have an array that contains a dictionary/hash of values and when I loop through the array, I get the value I need but any code after the for loop does not get executed because the console outputs:

```
TypeError: array[i] is undefined


var array = [
  {"name": "a", "pos": "C"},
  {"name": "b", "pos": "B"},
  {"name": "c", "pos": "W"},
];


for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]['pos'];
}
console.log("some other code");
```

I don't understand why this happens and I need the code underneath the for loop to execute. Does anyone know why this happens and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: Should be `< array.length`, not `<=`.

Comment: ^^^ also: missing `)` in `console.log(array[i]['pos'];`

Answer (score 2):

**Issues**

1. You haven't enclosed your first `console.log` function.
2. As an array is zero indexed making your condition `less than or equal to` will make the loop try to use an `undefined` part of the array (bigger than total length). Therefore use the `less than` operator.

**Fixed code**

```js
var array = [
  {"name": "a", "pos": "C"},
  {"name": "b", "pos": "B"},
  {"name": "c", "pos": "W"},
];


for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]['pos']);
}

console.log("some other code");
```