# I am new in programing as well as in javascript so please help me with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

```js
let itemsArr = ["Milk", "Bread", "Potato"];
let quantityArr = [5, 2, 3];

for (i = 0; i <= itemsArr.length; i++) {
  if (i <= itemsArr.length)
    console.log(itemsArr[i] + " - " + quantityArr[i]);
}
```

it should
Print the following result:

```
Milk - 5
Bread - 2
Potato - 3
```

but why it is Print the following result:

```
Milk - 5
Bread - 2
Potato - 3
undefined - undefined
```

Please help!

Comment: `<=` should be `<`

Comment: because `<=` goes one more.... 0,1,2,3.

Comment: If `i == itermsArr.length`, `itemsArr[i]` will *always* be `undefined`. Array indexes are zero-indexed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723311/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-arrayi-is-undefined same question, same number of elements!

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are 0-indexed, so the last element's index is always `length - 1`. Therefore, you should update your loop as follows:

```js
let itemsArr = ["Milk", "Bread", "Potato"];
let quantityArr = [5, 2, 3];

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(itemsArr[i] + ' - ' + quantityArr[i]);
}
```

Notice that there is also no need to check the status inside of the loop using the `if` statement, since it will always evaluate to true.

For added points, you can remove the `for` loop entirely, and instead use `forEach`:

```js
let itemsArr = ["Milk", "Bread", "Potato"];
let quantityArr = [5, 2, 3];

itemsArr.forEach((item, i) => {
  console.log(`${item} - ${quantityArr[i]}`);
});
```

Comment: you can even use forEach instead map because you are not returning anything :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `itemsArr.length` keeps number of all elements that are stored in an Array. For example for `let itemsArr = ["Milk", "Bread", "Potato"];` it is 3.
While index of array starts with 0 for Milk and ends with 2 for Potato.

This means that if you loop over the array you should use last index of an array, meaning that stop condition should look like `for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++)`  or `for (i = 0; i <= itemsArr.length - 1; i++)`

This is common error that is being made even by experienced programmers (maybe in a little bit more complicated situations;-) It even has its own name *off by one error* -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add, that you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for`.

Answer (score -5):

Delete if(i <= itemsArr.length)

Comment: Will not help, since the loop declaration is incorrect.

Comment: still need to make the <= loop into < since arrays are 0-indexed